# Parse_url not working correctly in a function

Tags: php, function, parsing

I have a redirect database, and I need to pull out urls and replace variables and redirect them. I have a function that pulls out the URL for the project and the parameters to replace, but when I call my support function to edit the parameter, parse_url doesn't work, I get ([PATH] => ) calling parse URL before passing the url to the second function does work. Here's the code:

```
function getURL($RID,$PID,$TEST)
    {

        //Skip this if it is a test:
        if(isset($TEST))
            $numID = $PID;
        else {
            $numID = $this->getNumericID($PID);
        } 
        $redirectValue = $this->checkRedirect($RID,$numID);

        switch ($redirectValue) {
            case 1:
                $query = "select projecturl,hasparameters,ID from projects where projectnumber=:rid limit 1";
                $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
                $statement->bindValue(':rid',$RID);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $url = $result["projecturl"];
                $query = "select parameter, `key` from d2crtest.parameters where projectID=:pid";
                $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
                $statement->bindValue(':pid',$result["ID"]);
                $statement->execute();
                while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
// if I put a return parse_url($url); here, it works
                    switch ($row["key"]) {
                        case 1:
                            $url = $this->addURLParameter($url, $row["parameter"], $numID);
                            ;                               
                            break;
                        (more code truncated)
```

In this block of code, parse_url does returns ([PATH]=>)

```
function addURLParameter($url, $paramName, $paramValue) {
         $url_data = parse_url($url);
         return $url_data;
```

Any reason why parse_url would work before the function call and not after?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, not unless something changes it in between (a reference for instance, or just a mistaken use of 'another'  `$url` variable). Are you a 100% sure the `$url` in  `getURL` is exactly the same as in `addURLParameter` (`var_dump` them to be sure)?

Comment: 100% -- I'm currently trying to modify this to parse_url then modify the query, and it works... for some unknown reason, addURLParameter is unable to parse_url

Comment: Are you sure that is in your _first_ loop, not in a second (third, , fourth...) one that has made `$url` into an array of its parts if I see your `addURLParameter` function (`return $url_data;` is an array)?

Comment: I am pretty sure, I put a "return $url;" and get the $url or a return parse_url($url) and it returns as expected... changing it to deal with the parsed_url is working it seems...

Comment: Well, the code as it stands can only stand 1 entry from `d2crtest.parameters` as I see it, it breaks as soon as there are 2 or more entries in it, as `$url` is not longer a parseable string but an array, and `parse_url(parse_url($url));` is of course a failure. If you _do_ do a `return $url;` in `addURLParameter`.. maybe should give us the _actual function there_.

Comment: `addUrlParameter()` builds a url and returns that, so each iteration should be parsing a freshly minted URL. I'm not sure what was causing the problem, but I fixed the code to read this: `$url = $this->addURLParameter(parse_url($url), $row["parameter"], $numID);` and changed addURLParameter to stop parsing, and it works.

Comment: That function probably has the error, not the `getURL` function. But hey, if it works now, I think we can close this as 'not reproducible'.

Comment: I agree Wrikken, thanks for your help :) ps how do I close it and say 'not reproducible' ?

Comment: Well, a close vote for non-reproducible eventually leads to a delete if enough people (5) agree. As the original asker, you can just delete the question yourself to speed up this process. Your problem is fixed, but it is unlikely this question helps others, so to keep Stack Overflow clean & searchable, those tend to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this works, `addURLParameter()` should return a url, so each successive row from the PDO would have a fresh URL to parse, but it didn't seem to be the case, so, I modified `addURLParameter()` to use a parsed_url() and called it like this: `$url = $this->addURLParameter(parse_url($url), $row["parameter"], $numID);` now I get this for a result: http://sometestserver.com/test/register.html?para1=test123&param2=Case4
 (which is the correct output)

Answer (score 0):

You have the following error in you're code (somewhat simplified, but I hope you get the idea):

```
// Initialize $url
$url = $result["projecturl"];
// $url will now be a string like '/example/project';
// ...
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $url = parse_url($url);
    // $url will now hold array('path' => '/example/project')
    // For the second row in your result-set (the second run of 
    // the while loop) that value will be given to parse_url(),
    // thus $url = parse_url(array(...)), resulting in NULL.
}

// Depending of the number of rows in your result-set, $url will be
// one of
// - '/example/project' (0 rows)
// - array('path' => '/example/project') (1 row)
// - NULL (even number of rows)
// - array('path' => '') (odd number of rows)
return $url;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, there's a return $url; after the switch block.

Comment: To be sure (because it will explain the error if that's not the case): the return is WITHIN the while-loop (just before the closing `}`)?

Comment: it is outside of the while and inside of the outer switch. If this causes the error, what is it?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an explenation (a comment was way to short)